# How to programmatically add a value to a file combo box for automation using TestStack.White

Tags: c#, combobox, automation

I am trying to automate my C# application, and part of that includes selecting a file inside an open file dialog. Once the window opens, I am able to grab the necessary UI element (a combo box) but cannot set the value to the file name that I want.

I believe this is because the combo box is empty in the beginning (i.e. I have never used this function manually and selected the file, so it is not stored in the combobox). Is there a way I can programmatically add an item to the combobox before selecting it? Here is my current code:

```
var fileUploadWindow = Program.application.GetWindows().Where(win => ((win.Name == ("File Upload Directory")))).FirstOrDefault();
var fileNameComboBox = fileUploadWindow.Get<ComboBox>(SearchCriteria.ByAutomationId("fileComboBox"));
fileNameComboBox.SetValue(fileName);
var openButton = fileUploadWindow.Get<Button>(SearchCriteria.ByAutomationId("openButton"));
openButton.Click();
```

Using this, when I call the SetValue() function, I receive an error:

```
Item of text 'fileName' not found.
```

How can I check to see if the file name is inside the combo box, and insert it if it isn't?

I would like to (if possible) handle this in the automation, without having to change the application itself. I also prefer to be able to insert the text into the combobox directly, instead of automating the file picker.

Comment: Thank you for downvoting without commenting. I appreciate the constructive criticism.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the solution.

As it turns out, an editable combo box can also be retrieved as a TextBox. So all I had to do was change two lines of code:

```
var fileNameTextBox = fileUploadWindow.Get<TextBox>(SearchCriteria.ByAutomationId("fileComboBox"));
fileNameTextBox.Text = fileName;
```